# Save text to file periodically

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to save some plain text periodically to a text file, and it will be really better if I can minimize the chance of corrupting the file in case the app gets terminated or the system restarts. What are the way to ensure that the plain text file is always good.

## Edit

I will run the program from USB drive, so want to make sure the file is still perfect if I eject the drive without closing the App.

Comment: To ensure it is always good you can work hard, pray to god or focus on the idea of the file being perfect. What specific problem are you having to ensure file's state is OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at using [transactions on the NTFS file system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa365008), assuming that the USB stick is formatted NTFS and your OS is Vista or better.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use option `FileMode.Create`, which overwrites existing files. Instead, use option `FileMode.Append` when creating the file stream, so that any text will be appended to the file without modifying last data.

However, try not to keep the files opened for long period, just open them and read or write and then `Dispose` them.

Answer (score 1):

Use File.[AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356.aspx) to open, append and close in one go.